# Which Insights implementation guarantees all exceptions get logged?

Tags: asp.net-web-api, azure-application-insights, global-asax, .net-4.8

We have a `global.asax.cs` file which contains this code...

**Approach One**

```
public class WebApiApplication : System.Web.HttpApplication
{
    TelemetryClient _telemetry = new TelemetryClient(new Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.Extensibility.TelemetryConfiguration() {
        InstrumentationKey = EnvironmentHelper.InstrumentationKey,
        ConnectionString = EnvironmentHelper.AppInsightsConnectionString
    });

    protected void Application_Start()
    {
        HttpConfiguration config = GlobalConfiguration.Configuration;

        GlobalConfiguration.Configure(WebApiConfig.Register);
    }
}
```

I am concerned that this will not log every and all exceptions to `Insights`. Would it be better to use this code?...

**Approach Two**

```
public class WebApiApplication : System.Web.HttpApplication
{
    TelemetryClient _telemetry = new TelemetryClient(...);

    protected void Application_Start()
    {
        HttpConfiguration config = GlobalConfiguration.Configuration;

        config.Filters.Add(new CustomExceptionFilter()); // ADDED LINE

        GlobalConfiguration.Configure(WebApiConfig.Register);
    }

    protected void Application_Error(Object sender, EventArgs e) // ADDED METHOD
    {
        Exception appException = Server.GetLastError();
        _telemetry.TrackException(appException);
    }
}

// ADDED CLASS
public class CustomExceptionFilter : ExceptionFilterAttribute
{
    TelemetryClient _telemetry = new TelemetryClient(...);

    public override void OnException(HttpActionExecutedContext actionExecutedContext)
    {
        _telemetry.TrackException(actionExecutedContext.Exception);
        base.OnException(actionExecutedContext);
    }
}
```

Are these approaches equal or is one more reliable?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure what do you mean `all exceptions get logged`.

Actually, `Application Insights` will auto collect unhandled exceptions thrown in the controller methods automatically for WebAPI 2+, exception the following scenario:

- Exceptions thrown from controller constructors.
- Exceptions thrown from message handlers.
- Exceptions thrown during routing.
- Exceptions thrown during response content serialization.
- Exception thrown during application start-up.
- Exception thrown in background tasks.

And For the other exceptions which are handled by application, still need to be tracked manually. You can use the `telemetryclient` to track these exceptions.

The referenced doc is [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-monitor/app/asp-net-exceptions#web-api).